# Applet not recoganizing sound file

Tags: java, applet

I'm just beginner of java programing.I'm currently facing this issue in APPLET programing, I refered lots of sites and forums but I doesn't get any suitable solution.

> problem: Applet is not recognize Sound file. help to solve this
>   problem

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class multimedia_applet extends Applet// implements ActionListener
{
    AudioClip audio;
    Button play;

    public void init()
    {
        audio=getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"sound.wav");

        System.out.println(audio);
        audio.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Applets are a dead technology 2) `System.out.println` - where to? 3) `System.out.println(audio);` you are printing out a `wav` file?

Comment: *"Applet is not recognize Sound file."* The JRE would not return that exact message, so I suspect it was in another language and translated. Could you add (copy/paste) the exact message in the original language as an [edit] to the question? See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Comment: i solved this problem.changing the jdk version...